# 2 completely different signatures on my passport

Tags: uk, passports

A few months back i went to the bank and they asked me to write another signature because mine was too far up amd i wrote it completely different as i changed my signature to something more simple. i am supposed to be going on holiday in 2 weeks and I’ve  been told it's invalid by a few people but some people are telling me not to listen to the passport office as all the border control care about is as long as the picture is you and they'll probably ask a few questions. I’m worried that i will get turned away at the airport but dont want to waste money that i do not have.  I have only just turned 18 will they maybe see it as a common mistake

Comment: Are you saying you’ve signed your passport twice? https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/signing-your-new-passport/signing-your-new-passport I’ve never had anyone look at my signature, as far as I recall

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.